# How to deploy application in windows azure with text file?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have created a mvc4 application with text file. I write some data in a file "ddd.txt". I wrote such address at my PC: "@D://Project//ddd.txt" and it worked finely. However, when I deploy my website on "azurewebsites.net", then I should write another address.

It is very important text file for me. And I would like to read data from it.

What address of directory should I write in my application to work him on Windows Azure server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try using App_Data (you can just add the directory if it doesn't exist in your project).

You could then load the file like this:

```
string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ddd.txt");
// load file here
```

The other option would be to store it in Blob storage, there is a good walkthough of the different features here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/